# Go package syscall conn.Read() is non-blocking and cause high CPU usage

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, go, system-calls

Strangely, in my case `Read()` is non-blocking and caused high CPU usage.

My code:

In function `main`:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":13798")


if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  for {
    // Wait for a connection.
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Handle the connection in a new goroutine.
    // The loop then returns to accepting, so that
    // multiple connections may be served concurrently.
    go reqHandler.TCPHandler(conn)

    runtime.Gosched()
  }
```

Function `TCPHandler`:

```
func TCPHandler(conn net.Conn) {
request := make([]byte, 4096)
  for {
    read_len, err := conn.Read(request)

    if err != nil {
        if err.Error() == "use of closed network connection" {
        LOG("Conn closed, error might happened")
        break
      }

      neterr, ok := err.(net.Error);
      if ok && neterr.Timeout() {
        fmt.Println(neterr)
        LOG("Client timeout!")
        break
      }
    }

    if read_len == 0 {
     LOG("Nothing read")
      continue
    } else {
      // do something
    }
    request := make([]byte, 4096)
  }
}
```

The problem is, `conn.Read()` is non-blocking, so every time it goes to `LOG("Nothing read")` then continue, this is causing high CPU usage. How to make `conn.Read()` a block call?

I've researched into `syscall` package but got stucked at `Syscall.Read()`
Since I found this issue on my OS X 10.8.3 here is the source code related:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go?h=Read#L898

I have no idea what `Syscall(SYS_READ, uintptr(fd), uintptr(_p0), uintptr(len(p)))` means.

Comment: this is a bad idea: `if err.Error() == "use of closed network connection"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not handling TCP correctly. When conn.Read() returns 0 bytes read, that means the peer has closed the TCP connection gracefully. You should probably close your end of the TCP connection in this case.

(Note that this is not special to Go, read()/recv() returning 0 on a TCP connection more or less universally means the other end has closed the connection)

Comment: Well... you are right, change `continue` to `break` works well