# What does "Syscall()" means in go package "syscall"?

Tags: linux, unix, go, system-calls, darwin

During the research of my another question [Go package syscall conn.Read() is non-blocking and cause high CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516948/go-package-syscall-conn-read-is-non-blocking-and-cause-high-cpu-usage), I read source code in `syscall` package.

Since I found my last issue on OS X 10.8.3, here is the source code related:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go?h=Read#L898

I have no idea what `Syscall(SYS_READ, uintptr(fd), uintptr(_p0), uintptr(len(p)))` means, actually I don't understand stuffs like `unsafe.Pointer` & `Syscall()`. How they works?

Besides, can anyone explain the comment `// THIS FILE IS GENERATED BY THE COMMAND AT THE TOP; DO NOT EDIT`, how and why these things work with specific platform by different implementations? And how `syscall` package generate these interfaces?

If someone can explain a specific function like `Read()` related with `syscall` could be help me understand it better, thanks.

Comment: Syscall(...) looks like a Go-ish edition of the old syscall() function from C. This (variadic) function allows you to perform arbitrary syscalls by providing the syscall number (here it is SYS_READ) and a set of arguments.

Comment: I think [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) will clarify a lot for you.

Comment: The `syscall` pack provides access to the low-level os syscalls.  The C-language versions are in `man(2)` (so `man read` will tell you what syscall.Read does) - I think they have the same name as the Go syscalls except without the capitial letter.  The file is probably auto-generated because it consists of lots of near-identical Go function wrapping different syscalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go Darwin `syscall` package [`func Read(fd int, p \[\]byte) (n int, err error)`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go) function is making a `read` ([`SYS_READ`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/zsysnum_darwin_amd64.go)) system call:

> [read Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/read.2.html)
>
> `ssize_t  read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);`
>
> `Read()` attempts to read `nbyte` bytes of data from the object
>   referenced by the descriptor `fildes` into the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

The Go Darwin `syscall` package [`Syscall`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s) function is:

```
// func Syscall(trap int64, a1, a2, a3 int64) (r1, r2, err int64);
// Trap # in AX, args in DI SI DX, return in AX DX

TEXT    ·Syscall(SB),7,$0
    CALL    runtime·entersyscall(SB)
    MOVQ    16(SP), DI
    MOVQ    24(SP), SI
    MOVQ    32(SP), DX
    MOVQ    $0, R10
    MOVQ    $0, R8
    MOVQ    $0, R9
    MOVQ    8(SP), AX   // syscall entry
    ADDQ    $0x2000000, AX
    SYSCALL
    JCC ok
    MOVQ    $-1, 40(SP) // r1
    MOVQ    $0, 48(SP)  // r2
    MOVQ    AX, 56(SP)  // errno
    CALL    runtime·exitsyscall(SB)
    RET
ok:
    MOVQ    AX, 40(SP)  // r1
    MOVQ    DX, 48(SP)  // r2
    MOVQ    $0, 56(SP)  // errno
    CALL    runtime·exitsyscall(SB)
    RET
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, `syscall.Syscall()` is simply a way to call some system specific APIs.

For example, Windows APIs typically use the `__stdcall` convention, which in general we would not be able to achieve without `syscall.Syscall()` in Go.

---

> func Syscall(trap, a1, a2, a3 uintptr) (r1, r2 uintptr, err Errno)

`trap`: The API we want to call.

`a1, a2, a3`: Arguments to that API.

`r1, r2, err`: Whatever that API returns. There are three, but we would probably use only one of them.

---

That's about it.